# Need advice on best workflow to export from 3ds Max to three.js

Tags: three.js, export, 3dsmax

I've been trying various ways, it seems that 3ds Max 2017 broke the native three.js exporter (only get 1kb .js exports). The commercial exporter from Prototech solutions seems to work OK, but exports everything into one big HTML file (which is not the result I'm after). I'm looking for the most flexible solution to incorporate 3ds Max animations in the future as well.

Any tips on how to convert materials from 3ds max to three.js would also be welcome.

Comment: My last big three.js project I exported from 3dsMax as as .obj and used the OBJLoader, that was a couple of years back though.

Comment: Ok, can I ask why you chose the obj-format? And why is it that most tutorials I find on google date from years back? Is three.js less used now?

Comment: I only chose .obj because that was a format that I was familiar with and the json exporter for 3ds max that is in the three.js repository did not work well. I'm not sure why most tutorials you are finding are so old, maybe they have been there a long time and have good SEO, or maybe because when three.js was new it was a bit of a fad and everyone was having a go. Three.js is probably used much more now I think (on real projects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [A3dsViewer](http://www.aptagraphis.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=20&Itemid=122) - includes quite good export to the three.js and allows to generate separate js file for every mesh.

Comment: Thank you! This helped quite a lot. At first I had some issues with the exported 3ds pivot points, but solved this by using this pluging: 'Batch Export / Import' by Jos Balcaen. *not sure if there would be an easier way? From there on I would use the A3dsViewer app and was amazed that even the materials 'worked' in html5.

Answer (score 0):

I would export to FBX then convert to JSON using the python script convert_to_threejs.py in:
utils\converters\fbx

You could also consider using GLTF:
https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_gltf.html

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a try, since I think it might add more flexibility in the process.